# RestEasy - UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type

Tags: java, spring, rest, resteasy, multipart

I have a spring MVC REST service that is supposed to receive mixed mime content. The controller is defined as

```
    @POST
    @Path("/createMime")
    @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String createMime(@Context ServletContext servletContext, MultipartInput input) throws MyRestException {

        logger.info("Processing /createMime");

        return "TEST";
    }
```

When i test the above i get the following error:

```
17:18:58,456 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed executing POST services/createMime: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:33) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:44) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:251) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:173) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49) [jboss-as-jpa-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_07]
```

If i change the @Consumes annotation so that it uses `@Consumes("multipart/form-data")` instead of `@Consumes("multipart/mixed")` then it works. What do i need to do to get it to work with multipart/mixed?

Here is how i am using the client to send the content to the REST service.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/MyRestService/rest/services/createMime");

        Scanner scanner = 
           new Scanner(new File("header.xml")).useDelimiter("\\Z");
           String messageHeader = scanner.next();
           scanner.close(); 

        FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("myImage.jpg"));
        StringBody header = new StringBody(messageHeader.toString());

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("header", header);
        reqEntity.addPart("payload", bin);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I have been struggling with this for quite a while so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that your client is *actually* sending a `multipart/form-data` request? The problem is in the client side.

Comment: @BalusC - Thats is interesting. How do you know it is and how do i send a multipart/mixed request?

Comment: Also note that you cannot upload file content with `multipart/mixed`.

Comment: Is this Spring MVC or Jersey? You're using Jersey annotations on what looks like a traditional Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the content type of the request? I believe that you client to send the content to `REST` service is posting a `multipart/form-data` request.

To understand how to send a `multipart/mixed request`, you should look at the documentation of `multipart` content type at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html, the section 7.2.1 suggests that `boundary` should be specified and used.

Basically, you need to follow below point to make a `multipart/mixed` request.

Include the boundary in the header

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
```

Each of the part in the request should have --boundary

```
 --gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
```

Last part should consist of --boundary--

```
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p--
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType instead putting in the string. It avoids the possible typos