# JAX-RS how to handle wrong content-type

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a REST service with a `@POST` method which `@Consumes("application/xml)"`.

However, if I make a POST request from my browser and I don't add

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

header to the request, I get an exception in my jboss

```
Failed executing POST : org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type
```

How is my servlet supposed to handle such cases?

Comment: Do you want that method to serve requests regardless of the content type?

Comment: No, I want this method to serve only application/xml content type and ignore all the others but without ugly exceptions

Comment: @mdzh What is the log level of the exception ? (should be warn from what is see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343405/resteasy-unsupportedmediatypeexception-cannot-consume-content-type) Because you can simply configure your logger for Production at ERROR level and you will not have this message anymore.

Comment: What response does the client get? If it is `415 Unsupported Media Type` then all is well from a REST perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an `ExceptionMapper` for the `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` and choose to handle it however you wish.  You're seeing this exception because you don't have a handler for it and resteasy is doing its out of the box handling.